# How to solve the problem about density function?

Tags: probability, definite-integrals

Let $f(x,y) =Ke^{ -( ax^2+2bxy+cy^2)  }$, and $a>0, c>0, b^2-ac>0$, if $f$ is a density function, so $K =$

A. $\frac 1 { \sqrt \pi} \left(ac-b^2 \right) $

B. $\frac 1 \pi \sqrt {ac-b^2} $

C. $\frac 1 {\sqrt \pi} \sqrt {ac-b^2} $

D. $\frac 1 \pi \left( ac-b^2 \right) $

I want to use the property of density function which is $\int _{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} P(x,y) \, dx \, dy=1$. But it seems too difficult to solve the integral or only I can't or it has other ways.

Comment: Hint: Try to make the power of the exponential term a square + stuff, also Gaussian dist.

Comment: You don't "solve" integrals; you _evaluate_ integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No calculation is needed here… it's given that $b^2 - ac > 0$ so $ac - b^2 < 0$ that's why B.) and C.) are not well defined and cannot be the answer.

A included $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$, C includes $\frac{1}{\pi}$ but the density is related to a bi-variate normal distribution hence the factor should include $\frac{1}{\pi}$ so it has to be D.

Comment: If it isn't a multiple choice question, how to solve it?

Comment: Then your way and keoxkeox hint is suitable